# Divide the Bonus

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I have a list (array) of employees who will be rewarded as follows:

- Const worker = [
  `{name: "John", prize: 1000, prioritize: 1},`
  `{name: "Andy", prize: 2000, prioritize: 2},`
  `{name: "Bill", prize: 2200, prioritize: 3},`
  `{name: :Carry", prize: 3100, prioritize: 4},`
  `{name: "Asawa", prize: 4000, prioritize: 5}`
  ]; //( array Worker is not fixed ...)
- Let TotalPrize = 7100 // fund bonus

Problem: I want to subtract TotalPrize for the list above (1-> 2-> 3 ...) so that Workers gets the full prize by order Prioritize:

- John: 1000 (full)
- Andy: 2000 (full)
- Bill: 2200 (full)
- Carry: 1900 (the list above, Carry must be 3100, but because TotalPrize = 7100 has been divided in advance for the first three remaining 1900)
- Asawa: 0 (because all the money for the first 4 people was divided)

Who has the solution and helps me to solve the problem, 2 weeks in desperation. So sad

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have tried options but have been to find not the final answer, i newbine in nodejs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please check the following code, hope it helps

```
let totalPrize = 7100;

const workers = [
    {
      name: "John",
      prize: 1000,
      prioritize: 1
    }, {
      name: "Andy",
      prize: 2000,
      prioritize: 2
    }, {
      name: "Bill",
      prize: 2200,
      prioritize: 3
    }, {
      name: "Carry",
      prize: 3100,
      prioritize: 4
    }, {
      name: "Asawa",
      prize: 4000,
      prioritize: 5
    }
  ];

const sortedWorkers = workers.sort((obj1, obj2) => obj1.prioritize > obj2.prioritize);

let finalResult = [];

sortedWorkers.map(worker => {
  if (totalPrize >= worker.prize) {
    finalResult.push({
      [worker.name]: worker.prize,
    });
    totalPrize -= worker.prize;
  } else {
    finalResult.push({
      [worker.name]: 0,
    });
  }
});

console.log(finalResult);
```

Comment: Great, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank so much to you

Comment: Glad to assist you.